# Function wont run twice inside - if else - statement

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to do a barcode lookup.

On the first attempt, the barcode gets looked up locally on the users barcodes.

If the is a duplicate, the function returns the first instance with a text saying "found locally"

If the barcode is not found locally, then it should do a global search.

The problem i have is with the if else statement, when the barcode is not found locally.

It should check to see if it is found globally if its not found locally.

```
public function updatePricelist(Request $request)
    {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $counter = count($_POST["product_name"]);

        //product barcode
        for ($x = 0; $x < $counter; $x++) {
            $product_barcode[] = $_POST["product_barcode"][$x];
        }

        //check the barcode locally
        $result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'local');

        if (!empty($result)) {

           $result =  "found locally";
        }

        else {

            $result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'global');

            if (!empty($result)) {

                $result =  "found globally";
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, $type)
    {

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

if ($type === 'local') {

            $db_barcodes = $this->getBarcodes($user_id, 'local');
        }

        if ($type === 'global') {

            $db_barcodes = $this->getBarcodes($user_id, 'global');
        }

        //merge arrays
        $merge_array = array_merge($db_barcodes, $product_barcode);

        function array_dup($ar)
        {
            return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($ar, array_unique($ar)));
        }

        $result = array_dup($merge_array);

        return current($result);

    }

    public function getBarcodes($user_id, $type)
    {


        if ($type === 'local') {

            $result = DB::select('SELECT products FROM vendor_pricelist WHERE user_id = ?', [$user_id]);
        }

        if ($type === 'global') {

            $result = DB::select('SELECT products FROM vendor_pricelist WHERE user_id != ?', [$user_id]);
        }

        $count_results = count($result);

        $temp = [];
        $temp_2 = [];

        for ($x = 0; $x < $count_results; $x++) {

            array_push($temp, json_decode($result[$x]->products));
        }

        $x = 0;

        while ($x < $count_results) {

            foreach ($temp[$x] as $value) {

                array_push($temp_2, $value[2]);
            }

            $x++;
        }

        $result = $temp_2;

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you execute this function call:

 $result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'local');
You return something even if the lookup wasnt successful.

You have to modify your barcodeLookUp function.

Comment: @B001ᛦ the if else not working and not sure why.

Comment: @Aaron please show code example

Comment: _the if else not working_ There is no `else if` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you are well. With your Http responses, Laravel tries to convert all responses to string or object and it seems that if your lookup does not return a value, Laravel will set the $result = false (boolean), and this will give you an error.

I have moved some code around to make things a bit clear. First thing is I added a else if statement to your updatePricelist() function to do the final check. This is to set $result variable to a string should the lookup not return any results.

```
$result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'global');

    if (!empty($result)) {

        $result = $result." found globally";
    }
    else {
        return "can save to db"; -> //this is to prevent the boolean response
    }
```

After this. I moved your array_dup() function outside the barcodeLookUp() function.

```
public function barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, $type)
{

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    if ($type === 'local') {

        $db_barcodes = $this->getBarcodes($user_id, 'local');
    }

    if ($type === 'global') {

        $db_barcodes = $this->getBarcodes($user_id, 'global');
    }

    //merge arrays
    $merge_array = array_merge($db_barcodes, $product_barcode);


    $result = $this->array_dup($merge_array);

    return current($result);

}

public function array_dup($ar)
{
    return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($ar, array_unique($ar)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
    //check the barcode locally
    $result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'local');

    if (empty($result)) {
        $result = $this->barcodeLookUp($product_barcode, 'global');

        if (!empty($result)) {
            return [
                "message" => "found globally",
                "result"  => $result,
            ];
        }

        return [
            "message" => "not found",
            "result"  => null,
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            "message" => "found locally",
            "result"  => $result,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Please check the $result value by dd, that can help you.